# How to implement caching for cluster setup in java springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, microservices

I want to implement cache for my service, so I used `spring-boot-starter-cache` in my application. But we have cluster setup(2 nodes) and currently if the request is going to one node it is not updating the other node data.How to implement a cluster setup cache in my java springboot application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an external cache like Redis.  It's quite fast and you can access it with Spring Data JPA.  You just set it up as an @Repository.  You'll need spring-boot-starter-data-redis as a dependency.  AWS offers it as a service called ElastiCache

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: If I use redis How it handles multiple nodes?

Comment: Well, both your nodes would store and retrieve values from the same Redis instance.  That way, there's only one cache.  It's independent of both your nodes and since there's only one, it cannot get out of sync.